# Storing processed objects in database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i have things that requires processing and rarely changes except with certain events to take advantage of memcached.  can i store a serial version of an object in a data field quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) (or [`marshal`](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html) or even [`JSON`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)) it and throw it in memcached.

Comment: thanks, though memcache is no good, what sql column type would i use?

Comment: pickle.dumps() returns a string. The problem is that this string can be pretty long so you have to make sure your SQL implementation can handle that.